# barcodescanner scans on empty table etc Android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

Hello I am using bar code scanner library https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner, but I am facing problem when ever I scan on my table for 10- 15 seconds it scans and also give me result randomly with bar code type "UPC_E,EAN_13 and so on", please guide me how to scan on barcode only not on empty things

This is how I am using this library

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), ScanActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, CommonConstants.MODE_BARCODE_FOR_ADD_ANOTHER);
```

**ScanActivity**

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    public static final String TAG = ScanActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String P9_AND_P10_DEVICE = "VTR-L09 VTR-L29 VTR-AL00 VTR-TL00 EVA-L09 EVA-L19 EVA-L29";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        if (P9_AND_P10_DEVICE.contains(Build.MODEL)) {
            mScannerView.setAspectTolerance(0.5f);
            Log.i(TAG, "Huawei Device\n" + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Any Other Device\n" + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
        }
        mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
    //   mScannerView.setFormats(Collections.singletonList(BarcodeFormat.));
        // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        mScannerView.setAspectTolerance(0.5f);
        setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view   }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();
      //  mScannerView.// Start camera on resume
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }


    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        // Do something with the result here
        Log.v(TAG, "---result.getText()"+result.getText()); // Prints scan results
        Log.v(TAG, "----SCANRESULT "+result.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

        if (result == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleResult: 1");
        } else if (result.getText() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleResult: 2");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleResult: 3");
        }


        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result", result.getText());


        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();

    }
```

I have tried another library also but still getting same issue https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner

Tried few more libraries but still same issue in these all libraries

- https://github.com/Credntia/MVBarcodeReader?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4457
- https://github.com/zxing/zxing
- https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/lib-demo-app
- https://github.com/bobekos/SimpleBarcodeScanner
- https://github.com/avaneeshkumarmaurya/Barcode-Reader

**Still looking for solution**

I have tried vision api examples but still facing same issues , only the thing is working firebase barcode scanner on sdk 21, but i want for sdk 18

Answer (score 1):

This may a library issue, Try using some other library

Recommended libraries:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

https://developers.google.com/vision

Comment: bro i am facing issue in zxing library also

Comment: yes i have tried vision api examples but still facing same issues , only the thing is working firebase barcode scanner on sdk 21, but i want for sdk 18